# Retrieve the input value by its name, which is within a div with an id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django

I'm trying to get the input value as the user types into the text field, using the `div`'s `id="search"` and the `name="vehicle"` within the div. What I have currently done returns `search_text` as an empty string. I've simplified the code into help prove my issue:

```html
<div id="search">
  <input type="text" name="vehicle">
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#search').keyup(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "http://localhost:8000/overview",
      data: {
        'search_text': $('#search').Children("input[name=vehicle]")
      },
      success: searchSuccess,
      dataType: 'html'
    });
  });
});

function searchSuccess(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
  $('#search-results').html(data);
}
```

I've tried the following:

```
'search_text': $('#search input')
```

and

```
'search_text': $('#search').Children("input[name=vehicle]")
```

Thanks

Comment: So as user types in the input you want input's value? Right?

Comment: Please note you are missing a `'` in `$('#search)`

Comment: `Children` needs to be `children`, JS is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First you are missing a `'` in `$('#search)`,

Second you need to use `.val()` if you wish to get the value from the input.

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    $('#search').keyup(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost:8000/overview",
            data: {
                'search_text': $('#search input[name=vehicle]').val()
            },
            success: searchSuccess,
            dataType: 'html'
        });
    });
});
```

**Demo**

```js
$(document).ready( function(){
    $('#search').keyup(function() {
        console.log($('#search input[name=vehicle]').val())
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="search">
  <input type="text" name="vehicle">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I've replaced the line of code but it is still returning an empty string.

Comment: @LewisHepburn Try look at the demo i added, You should work, try adding `console.log($('#search input[name=vehicle]').val())` just before your ajax

Comment: Thanks very much Carsten! It turns out the problem is down to my Application for not updating the .js file.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use oninput event like this

```
 document.querySelector('input[name=vehicle]').oninput=function(){
    alert(this.value)
 };

OR

 $('input[name=vehicle]').oninput(function(){
 alert(this.value)
 });
```